# Deploying XAMPP to Google App Engine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, xampp

I have an Android mobile chat app using websockets and server running on XAMPP in PHP. At present, it is simply running on my local machine during the initial development process.

I was thinking of rewriting using PubNub for a production level application, but a review of Google App Engine provided it could be a simpler alternative. Is it possible to migrate my XAMPP configuration with PHP server and MySQL database onto the Google cloud platform? What drawbacks are there in this transition?

Answer (score 1):

For this I will suggest you to create your application locally using Google AppEngine SDK [1] with your configuration on XAMPP and see if it is working or not. The Google AppEngine SDK is the simulator for GAE Cloud, so if it is working fine with SDK then there is high probability it will work in the production environment.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

Comment: ...The server logic for both XAMPP and LAMP are built in PHP, and the Android app to pull in the XML files is built natively in java-android,